# Experimental methods for finding London penetration depth

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics

I have been doing some readings on superconductivity and have come across the [London penetration depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_penetration_depth). I somewhat understand how it comes into play with the London equation and Ampère's law.

Right now, I am having a hard time finding out how one would, if one is given a material that is said to be a superconductor and knowing only the critical temperature, be able to determine the $\lambda_L$ of this material.

I know that it is possible to use [μSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon_spin_spectroscopy), but how exactly would one go about doing that? Also, is that the only experimental method if one does not know anything else about the material?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good introductory explanation to μSR and using it to measure the penetration depth here.

[Spin-polarized muons in condensed matter physics](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0207699)

It basically works because the magnetic field distribution in a type-II superconductor depends on the penetration depth and the μSR technique can be used to measure the field distribution in a material.

Another method is to use a tunnel diode oscillator.